# Meteor Package.describe() method doesn't exist after 0.9 upgrade

Tags: meteor, package, upgrade, meteorite

I'm getting the following error after newly upgrading to Meteor 0.9.0.1 and updating my [package.js](https://github.com/zeroasterisk/Meteor-Throttle/blob/0.9-upgrade/package.js) file to match [documentation on packages](http://docs.meteor.com/#packagejs)

```
W20140903-17:30:20.305(-4)? (STDERR) /Users/admin/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.26.p03e91++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140903-17:30:20.305(-4)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20140903-17:30:20.306(-4)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20140903-17:30:20.308(-4)? (STDERR) TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'describe'
W20140903-17:30:20.308(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/zeroasterisk:throttle/package.js:1:44
W20140903-17:30:20.308(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/zeroasterisk:throttle/package.js:22:3
W20140903-17:30:20.309(-4)? (STDERR)     at /Development/Meteor/Meteor-Throttle-Example/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
W20140903-17:30:20.309(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140903-17:30:20.309(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/admin/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.26.p03e91++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140903-17:30:20.309(-4)? (STDERR)     at /Development/Meteor/Meteor-Throttle-Example/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8

$ meteor --version
Meteor 0.9.0.1

$ meteor list
standard-app-packages   1.0.0  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in y...
autopublish             1.0.0  Publish the entire database to all clients
insecure                1.0.0  Allow all database writes by default
bootstrap-3             0.0.0  Provides bootstrap 3.
showdown                1.0.0  Markdown-to-HTML processor
underscore              1.0.0  Collection of small helpers: _.map, _.each, ...
package-version-parser  1.0.6  Parses Meteor Smart Package version string
zeroasterisk:throttle   0.2.1  A secure means of limiting interactions (email...
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...  can you?

Comment: Hmm... `package.js` looks fine. Maybe try re-installing meteor `mv ~/.meteor ~/.meteor.bak && curl https://install.meteor.com | sh`, then if no dice, lodge a bug at `https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had the same issue. The problem here is that you have the package in the root app folder `app/zeroasterisk:throttle` when it should be `app/packages/zeroasterisk:throttle`. Put your package inside the packages folder and it'll be solved.

Answer (score 0):

you can to try read the official guide for the packages migration. In this guide explains how to fix broken packages. The url is

https://hackpad.com/Migrating-Packages-zN0we9sIjkH

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions -- as it turns out, it must have been some other Package.  I created a new Meteor app and added my Package and it worked fine :/

So I don't know the exact cause, perhaps something overwriting the Package object, but anyway getting around it was easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue that was preventing me from deploying my app. The reason was that I had a packages directory defined in my client folder (app/client/packages). This should however be in the main directory of the project (app/packages). After I removed package folder in the client folder the application was able to deploy without a problem.

I had a Package.describe() method call that was throwing an error which helped me track down this problem.